# При смене ip сервера не загружаются файлы проверки в Apache2 (Ubuntu, Debian)

Tags: ubuntu, apache, debian, ip, apache2

Ситуация в следующем:
Установил Debian 10.1, по умолчанию после установки стоял динамический ip. Через сканер сети определил ip, ввел его в браузере и получал страницу "It works".
в файле /etc/network/interfaces настроил статический ip, перезагрузился. В сканере определился новый ip, ввожу его и получаю: "Не удается получить доступ к сайту
Сайт 192.168... не позволяет установить соединение."

То же самое проделал в Ubuntu 18.04. но ещё попробовал изменить сетевые настройки c помощью утилиты Netplan и файла /etc/netplan/*.yaml., при этом в /etc/network/interfaces закомментировал все строки, а то определялось 2 ip одного сервера. Результат тот же!

Возвращаю Ip в статике на тот, который сначала выдавался автоматом - всё работает!..

В чём может быть проблема???

Comment: по-моему, вполне очевидно, что проблема — в том, что вы проделали. и пока вы скрываете подробности, ничего более конкретного сказать не получится.

Comment: При перезагрузке интерфейсы стартуют без ошибок? Статические адреса не заняты другими устройствами в сети? 
Что показывает `ifconfig -a` ? Что внутри `/var/log/apache2/error.log` ?

Comment: @Николай Габараев, проблема решилась, можно сказать сама собой. Я просто плюнул, полностью выключил сервер, на следующий день решил еще немного посидеть, включил, попробовал ввести текущий новый ip и все открылось.. Не знаю, в чем крылась проблема